# Running cmd with C# and parameter

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I have to compile a game like this

love "C:\testgame"

in the cmd. So I use this code, but it seems like the parameter is missinterpreted. Also, the console closes after a sec. But if I use Messagebox.Show I can see the command in the cmd is the same I manually use (and this works)

```
Process cmd = new Process();

        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput =
        true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput =
        true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.Write(@"cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\LOVE\");
        MessageBox.Show("love \""+fldBrowDiag.SelectedPath.ToString()+@"\"+lsb_projects.SelectedItem.ToString()+"\"");
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.Close();
```

Comment: Why can't you run "love" directly instead of running "cmd.exe?"

Comment: @Jacob: Probably because he couldn't use `@"cd %ProgramFiles(x86)%\LOVE\"` to change the working directory in that case.

Comment: In the `StartInfo` object, you can set its `WorkingDirectory` property to achieve the same effect as executing a `cd` command.

Comment: BTW the console window closes after 1 second, because the code doesn't wait for the process to finish but closes it immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the "cd" command you issue will probably fail because you don't have quotes around the argument. (that program files env variable will have spaces in it.)

Second, instead of writing to stdin directly, maybe consider using the "/c" switch that will instruct cmd.exe to execute the specified commands directly. You can separate the commands with '&&'.

Comment: In the end, this solution is the best. I was so keen on the cmd, that i forgot a simple starting parameter can do it too.
`Process cmd = new Process();
 
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\LOVE\love.exe";

            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "\""+fldBrowDiag.SelectedPath.ToString()+@"\"+lsb_projects.SelectedItem.ToString()+"\"";
            
cmd.Start();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this to simplify things:

```
var process = Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\LOVE\love.exe", @"C:\game") {
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\LOVE" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just start cmd with the correct arguments to launch your process?

eg `cmd /C love "c:\game"` to close after finish or `cmd /K love "c:\game` to leave open after finish?